# How to change color of lines in each iteration of a for loop in Java

Tags: java, swing, colors

I have an ArrayList called `theLayers` which stores collections of points (layers), and I would like each layer to have a distinct color. At each iteration of the for loop I set the graphics to a new color and draw the points of each distinct layer. However, upon debugging, I have noticed that the points are set to the last color that was generated.

I have tried placing the random color assignment at different locations in the code, and I have debugged the code to ensure that the colors are indeed being changed during each iteration.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Drawer extends JPanel {
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> theLayers;

public Drawer() {
    this(new ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>());
}

public Drawer(ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> coordinates) {
    this.theLayers = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>(coordinates);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
super.paintComponent(g);

Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
for(ArrayList<Point> coordinates:theLayers) {
    int R = (int) (Math.random( )*256);
    int G = (int)(Math.random( )*256);
    int B= (int)(Math.random( )*256);
    Color randomColor = new Color(R, G, B);
    g2d.setColor(randomColor);
    for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {
        g2d.drawLine(coordinates.get(i).x, coordinates.get(i).y,
                coordinates.get(i).x, coordinates.get(i).y);
    }
}
}
}
```

I want the color of each layer to be distinct, not the same color. Thank you.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code.

Comment: You should NOT be generating random colors in the paintComponent() method. You can't control when Swing determines a components needs to be repainted. The color should be randomized and stored in the ArrayList as you add each object to the ArrayList. This means you need a custom object that contains the color and the object you want painted. Check out the  `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example of this approach.

Comment: @camickr I did as you said and created a custom object... but this did not resolve my issue.

Comment: @Hossmeister, 1) where is your [mcve] demonstrating the problem? 2) How do you expect us to help if we can't see the code? 3) but more importantly you need to learn how to debug your own code, so how is your code different than the working example code you were given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349066/how-to-change-color-of-lines-in-each-iteration-of-a-for-loop-in-java#comment97422919_55349066) have a custom point object that has color attribute:

```
class ColoredPoint extends Point{

    private final Color color;

    ColoredPoint(int x, int y,Color color) {
        super(x, y);
        this.color = color;
    }

    Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

And use it in `Drawer` class :

```
class Drawer extends JPanel {

    private final ArrayList<ArrayList<ColoredPoint>> theLayers;
    private static final int W = 700, H =700;
    public Drawer() {
        this(new ArrayList<ArrayList<ColoredPoint>>());
    }

    public Drawer(ArrayList<ArrayList<ColoredPoint>> coordinates) {
        theLayers = new ArrayList<>(coordinates);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(W,H));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));

        for(ArrayList<ColoredPoint> cPoints:theLayers) {
            g2d.setColor(cPoints.get(0).getColor());
            for (int i = 0; i < cPoints.size(); i++) {
                g2d.drawLine(cPoints.get(i).x, cPoints.get(i).y,
                        cPoints.get(i).x, cPoints.get(i).y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use this [link](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/WiHo1wmCpx) for an mcve. Copy paste the entire code into one file (SwingTestFrame.java) and run.